# AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'сlose'. Trying to close opened .txt file

Tags: python

This function opens .txt file and creating another one filled with utf-8 code of each symbol. Now there is an:

```
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'сlose' with string - coded_file.сlose()
```

Why does `file.close()` work, but `coded_file.сlose()` does not?

```
def code():
   file_name = input("Введите имя файла, который необходимо закодировать: ")
   file = open(file_name, "r")
   message = file.read()
   file.close()
   message_list = list(message)
   coded_message_list = []
   for letter in message_list:
       coded_letter = letter.encode('utf8')
       coded_message_list.append(coded_letter)
   coded_string = ''.join(str(coded_message_list))
   coded_string = coded_string.replace("[","")
   coded_string = coded_string.replace("]","")
   coded_file = open("Закодированный файл.txt", "w")
   coded_file.write(coded_string)
   coded_file.сlose() # here is error
   print('Создан файл "Закодированный файл.txt".')
```

Comment: I can't see anything obvious. Try restarting your IDE. `TextIOWrapper` extends `IOBase`, and `IOBase` has a `close` method, so idk why there would be an issue here.

Comment: What does `dir(coded_file)` show?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error on my machine. Utf / cyrillic doesn't seem to be a problem here. What OS / python are you on?

Comment: Easy solution: Use a context manager!

Comment: The "c" in the non-working `close()` is actually a Cyrillic character of some sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `с` in the later `сlose` is not actually the letter `c`.

```
In [1]: 'сlose' == 'close'
Out[1]: False

In [2]: ord('сlose'[0])
Out[2]: 1089
```

In my terminal they look a little different but in my browser they look identical.